# Where is the progress bar hanging, if not on CPU or IO?

Tags: update, processor-speed

I ran `apt upgrade` and was wondering why it took so long. It was waiting a lot on 33% and other percentages.

Apparently, I had no CPU usage and I cannot see a lot of `io wait`. Where is it actually so slow?

The `dpkg` process was not always on top of `htop`. I just happen to have it on the screenshot by chance. Most of the time the CPU was practicaally idle on even lower percentages of load. Why is `dpkg` not using more power to unpack the files?

```
pi@RPi64:~ $ sudo iostat
Linux 5.15.52-v8+ (RPi64)   07/07/22    _aarch64_   (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.57    0.07    0.56    4.20    0.00   94.59

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
loop0             0.63         5.14         2.10         0.00     982261     401268          0
mmcblk0           1.86        85.87        24.55         0.00   16414353    4692773          0
sda               0.26         0.02        25.30         0.00       3942    4835939          0
sdb               3.58       341.13       176.03         0.00   65208457   33648277          0
sdc               1.14        46.39        93.32         0.00    8867137   17838776          0
```

[image: progress bar]

[image: htop]

Comment: DO NOT post illegible pictures of text post TEXT

Comment: I was able to read the pictures which where not just text but I cropped them and uploaded again.

Comment: You might be able to read the pictures, but those of us who were born before well before Linux might not have as good eyesight as you. Your pictures cannot be run through a text reader. Just copy and paste the text, and fix the formatting.

Comment: Didn't know there where people who use a text reader. The first picture is showing the installation progress in `apt` in Raspbian 64bit. It just  shows the progress bar beeing stuck at some percentage. The second picture is showing `htop` with a load over all 4 CPUs of just about 4 percent. I am not able to reproduce them now.